# Pagination in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a MySQL Strored Procedure ,I want to call the Stored Procedure using Hibernate and want to display the Results with Pagination.

I have tried the below Code:

```
public List<Master> getAbsentDetails(String fromdate, String todate,int pno) {
        Query query=getSession().getNamedQuery("AbsentReportproc");
        System.out.println("Test");
        query.setParameter("_fromdate", fromdate);
        query.setParameter("_todate", todate);
        query.setMaxResults(10);
        query.setFirstResult(ps*(pno-1));

        List<Master> empList=query.list();
        return empList;}
```

But when i Execute the above  code I'm displayed with the following Error:

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
Feb 1, 2013 10:08:11 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 10' at line 1
```

**Note:**
If i remove the below statement

```
  query.setMaxResults(10);
```

then I'm displayed with Result of My Stored Procedure in a jsp page

thanks

Comment: whats your log level set to for hibernate?  If you set it to a ALL I'm pretty sure you can see the generated query.

Comment: Actually you have to set the hibernate.show_sql property to true in order to see the generated SQL.

Answer (score 2):

when i faced the same issue i moved the  set maxresult to below  and working fine

```
criteria.setFirstResult(10* (pageNumber - 1));
criteria.setMaxResults(10);
```

Comment: How do i create criteria object by passing  name of the Stored Procedure as argument ?

Comment: @Kumar  this  is out of topic to the current question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608667/unable-to-get-multiple-table-entities-through-stored-procedure-using-hibernate

Comment: in the above link i mentioned how i used stored procedure ...you can use like that ..my problem is something else in that qtn ..i am able to get  the results of stored procedure ..you can use it

Comment: In that link you have created Query object by passing your SQLQuery as argument ,but how can i use criteria to setmaxresult() etc for pagination

Comment: In that link I didn't find any Criteria

Comment: can i create criteria object by passing MysqlStoredProcedure as argument?I want to implement pagination

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23754/discussion-between-the-suresh-atta-and-kumar)