# java arraylist iteration having a ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, arraylist

I have model class:

```
public class RecordSet {
    private DateRange daterange;
    private Master master;
    public DateRange getDaterange() {
        return daterange;
    }
    public void setDaterange(DateRange daterange) {
        this.daterange = daterange;
    }
    public Master getMaster() {
        return master;
    }
    public void setMaster(Master master) {
        this.master = master;
    }
}


public class DateRange {
    private Date ddate;

    public Date getDdate() {
        return ddate;
    }

    public void setDdate(Date ddate) {
        this.ddate = ddate;
    }

}

public class Master  {

    private String empcode;
    private String empname;
    private String dept;


    public String getEmpcode() {
        return empcode;
    }
    public void setEmpcode(String empcode) {
        this.empcode = empcode;
    }
    public String getEmpname() {
        return empname;
    }
    public void setEmpname(String empname) {
        this.empname = empname;
    }
    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }
    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

}
```

I have a statement like this

```
List<RecordSet> list = (List<RecordSet>) query.list();
```

when the above statement get's executed I'm gettind the list Objects and Each object holds two items(Master,DateRange)?

Could any one How can I get those two model class objects

**I've tried but facing classcast exception:**

```
List<RecordSet> list = (List<RecordSet>) query.list();
            for(int i=0;i<list.size(); i++){
                Object set=list.get(i);
                Master masetr=(Master)set;

                System.out.println(masetr);
                }
```

thanks

Comment: Casting doesn't work like that; you can't magically cast a list with a generic type to a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can't cast them if they are not realted .
```

The class of the object you're casting and the class you're casting it to must be related by inheritance; that is, you can cast an object only to an instance of its class's sub- or superclass-not to any random class.

`Side note`:  Casting downward in the class hierarchy is automatic, but casting upward is not.

Comment: I had used inheritance But still facing ClassCastException,Could you provide me Source Code here ?How you typeCasted and how you got your Entity refrences after calling query.list() method?

Comment: DateRange and Master extends RecordSet

Comment: My Procedure returns Employee Details From Master Table and one Date coulmn from DateRange Table like your case here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608667/unable-to-get-multiple-table-entities-through-stored-procedure-using-hibernate

Comment: So you can use Master masetr=get(i);

Comment: I am adding like this  query.addentity(Master); and query.addentity(DateRange)

Comment: If i add 2 entites like above comment then I am facing ClassCastException

Comment: This statement Master masetr=get(i) is working for single Entity i.e if i add query.addentity(Master);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23837/discussion-between-the-suresh-atta-and-kumar)

Comment: yes I tried query.addentity(Master.Class);,then I'm getting the results successfully,if i add two entities to the query object ,then I'm having the problem of typecasting

Comment: ohho..kumar ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608667/unable-to-get-multiple-table-entities-through-stored-procedure-using-hibernate  ... i am asked the same qtn yaar ..  noboady replied ...as of now i am doing with single entity only ..and your first question has been resolved right ?? this is second question i  think

Comment: No ,first question was also not resolved,I'm having some kind of Pagination Problem

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
List<Object> list = query.list();
for(Object obj:list){
   RecordSet rs = (RecordSet)obj;
   Master ms = rs.getMaster();
   System.out.println(ms.getEmpCode()); //all things you need to print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for (Object obj : query.getResultList()) {
    Object[] objArray = (Object[]) obj;
    Master ms = new Master();
    ms.setxxxx(objArray[0].toString());
    ms.setxxxx(objArray[1].toString());
    list.add(ms);
```