# How to write jstl code for Hibernate returning two Entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jstl, hibernate-mapping

I have a Hibernate Code like below which returns single Entity class:

```
SQLQuery query = 
                session.createSQLQuery("select * from Employee");
            query.addEntity(Employee.class);
                       List<Employee> emplist= query.list();
```

for above code my Jstl working code is:

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${requestScope.size!=0}">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>
EmployeeName
</th>
<th>EmployeeDepartment</th>

</tr>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.absentlist}" var="emps">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${emps.empno}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${emps.empname}"/></td>

</tr>


</c:forEach>
```

**But My Requirement is to write a jstl code For a Hibernate which is Returning two Entities**

Here is my Hibernate Code:

```
SQLQuery query = session
                    .createSQLQuery("CALL AbsentReportproc(:_fromdate,:_todate)");
            query.addEntity(Master.class);
            query.addEntity(DateRange.class);
            query.setParameter("_fromdate", "2012-12-03");
            query.setParameter("_todate", "2012-12-04");

            List<RecordSet> obj = query.list();     
            Iterator it=obj.iterator();

             while(it.hasNext())
                {
                    Object[] obj1 = (Object[]) it.next();
                    for (int i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {

                        RecordSet set=(RecordSet)obj1[i];
                        if(set instanceof Master){
                         System.out.println("Employee Code"+((Master) set).getEmpcode());
                         System.out.println("Employee Dept"+((Master) set).getDept());
                         System.out.println("Employee Name"+((Master) set).getEmpname());                   
                        }
                        if(set instanceof DateRange){
                         System.out.println("AbsentDate"+((DateRange) set).getDdate());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Could any one provide me the JSTL Code to display the above results on jsp page?

Comment: So, is it a `List<RecordSet>` or a `List<Object[]>`? What should be displayed? How?

Comment: It's not clear from your question why the JSTL you've provided wouldn't work for both cases. Can you post the code for your backing object?

Comment: when I called the list() method the I'm avialble with Object array items which is having obj[0]={Master obj,DateRange obj} etc.....

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659209/java-arraylist-iteration-having-a-classcastexception

Comment: I have used but forgot to mention public class Master extends RecordSet and  public class DateRange extends RecordSet in the above link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you in fact have a `List<Object[]>`, and each `Object[]` in the list contains an instance of Master as its first element, and an instance of DateRange as its second element.

Start by writing a class which contains those two objects, which will make your code easier to read:

```
public class MasterAndDateRange {
    private Master master;
    private DateRange dateRange;
    // constructor and getters omitted for brevity
}
```

Then iterate through your `List<Object[]>` and create a `List<MasterAndDateRange>`.

Then store this list in a request attribute (`"listOfMasterAndDateRange"`, for example).

Then, in the JSP, use the JSTL to iterate over this list:

```
<c:forEach var="masterAndDateRange" items="listOfMasterAndDateRange">
   ...
   <c:out value="${masterAndDateRange.master.foo}"/>
   ...
   <c:out value="${masterAndDateRange.dateRange.bar}"/>
   ...
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Could you give me the Sample code How Could i iterate please,I had tried but facing type casting exception

Comment: Object list = query.list();
   
   Iterator it=list.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext()){
    MasterAndDateRange obj1 =  (MasterAndDateRange)it.next(); 
    
   }

Comment: I had tried but facing type casting exception Object cannot be cast to MasterAndDateRange,Could you provide me the Sample code please

Comment: Re-read the first 2 sentences of the answer: you have a List<Object[]>. It's up to you to transform this List<Object[]> into a List<MasterAndDateRange>. by iterating through the List<Object[]>, transforming each Object[] into a MasterDateRange instance, and adding then to a new List<MasterDateRange>.

Comment: No, I can't. It's your job to provide the code. Iterating on a list isn't something you should be afraid of.

Comment: Could you tell me my Iteration logic was correct or not? in this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743952/hibernate-returning-two-pojos-and-display-the-results-on-jsp-using-jstl

Comment: when i execute the logic in the above link I'm not able to get the values

Answer (score 0):

AS per your code you are calling stored procedure and not just single table query. Hence hibernate will return the Object list only.

You needs to iterate the loop and populate the required object.

Other option is as suggested by @JB Nizet.