# Get data from 3 tables using dynamic query

Tags: hibernate, liferay, liferay-6, dynamicquery

I have 3 tables user_, userTracker, userTrackerPath

user_ has userId as Pk. which is Fk in userTracker
userTracker has UserTrackerId as pk which is Fk in userTrackerPath
and userTrackerPath has userTrackerPathId as Pk.

user_ tables has fields firstName, LastName, loginIp, lastLoginIp
userTracker has fields remoteAddr, remoteHost
userTrackerPath has fields path_, pathDate

All these are the fileds that i want.

I have written an sql query and it runs successfully for me, but i want the result using Dynamic query .

Here is my sql query.

```
select concat(U.firstName," ",U.lastName) as     FullName,U.loginIp,U.lastLoginIp,UT.remoteAddr,substring(UT.modifiedDate,1,10) as Date,UTP.path_ from demo.User_ U, demo.UserTracker UT, demo.UserTrackerPath UTP where ((U.userId=UT.userId) and (UT.userTrackerId=UTP.userTrackerId));
```

I wrote dynamic query with projections i am confused how will i be joining them.

```
//Dynamic Query For User Class

        DynamicQuery dynamicQuery_user = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(User.class,PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader())
                .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("userId"))
                .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("firstName"))
                .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("lastName"))
                .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("loginIp"))
                .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("lastLoginIp"));

        //Dynamic Query For User and UserTracker Class

        DynamicQuery dynamicQuery_userTracker  = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(UserTracker.class,PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader())
                .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("modifiedDate"))
                .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("remoteAddr"));


        //Dynamic Query for UserTracker and UserTrackerPath

        DynamicQuery dynamicQuery_userTrackerPath  = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(UserTrackerPath.class,PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader())
                .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("path_"))
                .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("pathDate"));
```

Also i tried..

```
        dynamicQuery_userTracker.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("userId").in(dynamicQuery_user));

        dynamicQuery_userTrackerPath.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("userTrackerId").in(dynamicQuery_userTracker));
```

I knows my method is incorrect. Any Views or suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also waiting for the answer for this ..i tried with stored procedure .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608667/unable-to-get-multiple-table-entities-through-stored-procedure-using-hibernate

Comment: Hey You must go through.http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6729269?_19_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.liferay.com%2Fhome%3Fp_p_id%3D3%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dmaximized%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26_3_keywords%3Ddynamic%2Bquery%2B%26_3_struts_action%3D%252Fsearch%252Fsearch   Hope it helps, I am trying to get on exact solution to my problem using this concept.

Comment: Have you run the code you posted?

Answer (score 1):

Jay I think you [cannot do joins](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10926083) with the DynamicQuery API. You can do [subqueries](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6729269) with the in and notin methods.

Comment: Great commentary, but if you check in detail the initial post you'll notice that his main problem is gathering fields from different tables. And he's asking if, from a Liferay's DQ approach, it's possible to do it or not. And I wonder so.