# How do I map return value from Stored Procedure to my entity class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

How do I map return value from Stored Procedure to my entity class in Hibernate. If selected column is been queried in SP.

Comment: Just set the property yourself with the returned value. What is SP?

Comment: @Bart SP--> Stored procedure.

Comment: <sql-query name="NotificationDetails">
        <![CDATA[call getNotificationDetails(:City,:Latitude,:Longitude)]]>
    </sql-query>
Entity class is Message.java

Comment: Might helpful :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608667/unable-to-get-multiple-table-entities-through-stored-procedure-using-hibernate

Comment: yup...
BEGIN
SELECT  MERCHANT_ID , NOTIFICATION_ID 
FROM TBL_NOTIFICATION_DETAILS WHERE MERCHANT_ID 
END

Comment: @Suresh it works if i select all column .. but does not work for selected column ..

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("callStockStoreProcedure")
    .setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
List result = query.list();
for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
    Stock stock = (Stock)result.get(i);
    System.out.println(stock.getStockCode());
}
```

see this article

**[How to call stored procedure in Hibernate](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/)**

Comment: error java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to Message

Comment: This is how i am calling
List messages = session.getNamedQuery("NotificationDetails")
                  .setParameter("City", city)
                  .list();
                  for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
             Message message = (Message)messages.get(i);
             System.out.println(message.getMerchant_id());
            }