# How to Map multiple tables obtained from stored procedure to Java bean using Hibernate or JDBC

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

[image]

I am getting five different tables as output while executing stored procedure.
How can I map the result produced by stored procedure into single java bean (POJO class) using either Hibernate or JDBC.

Please refer above image. Thank u.

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit more, what exactly u r trying to achieve from this ? Have u done any research on this ?

Comment: When I execute stored procedure, it gives output in form of multiple tables(as shown in image.). I am not getting, how to map the output(which is in multiple tables) into java pojo class.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608667/unable-to-get-multiple-table-entities-through-stored-procedure-using-hibernate